# Is there any quantitative index to describe the strength of a 'trend'?

Tags: index, trends

I am using a trend following strategy in the stock market. If you look at the price chart, you can tell one stock's trend is stronger than the other. Now I want to develop an index to calculate the 'strength' of the trend, is there any good method for this?

Comment: There are a few different ways to quantify "strength," a little more detail about what parameters your using would help.  In any case, looking at some technical analysis books/sites might be best for what you're looking for.

Comment: Time-series or Regression models could be an answer. So, there are many models that it's up to you. I think VECM(vector error correction model) is suitable for this case.

Comment: Hi bigbug, I've closed your question since it is *overly broad*.  There are far too many technical indicators to list here, and many of them attempt to quantify "strength" of a trend.  Please be more specific.

Comment: It's an interesting question, I think it could be possible to provide a brief answer with at least an indication of where to research further.